# Using BibTeX with latexmk

Tags: bibtex, latexmk

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 under Windows XP.  I have the following directory structure for my document:

- `D:\MyTeX`
- `D:\MyTeX\BibTeX`
- `D:\MyTeX\IPMcast`

File latexmkrc contains the line:

```
$bibtex = 'bibtex -include-directory=D:/MyTeX';
```

File IPMCast\ipmc.tex contains the line:

```
\bibliography{BibTeX/network}
```

When I use the command:

```
latexmk -r latexmrc ipmc
```

my document is created minus the BibTeX references.

When I manually use the commands:

```
latex ipmc
bibtex -include-directory=D:/MyTeX ipmc
latex ipmc
latex ipmc
```

files `ipmc.bbl` and `ipmc.blg` are created and my document is properly created with references.

I have tried several variations of `latexmkrc` using apostrophes, quotation marks, back slashes, forward slashes, etc with no luck.  The original document was created in 2007 and I believe everything worked properly then.  How should I define `$bibtex` in `latexmkrc` file to get this to work?

Comment: @Martin: I had already been wondering why _you_ of all people didn't use `<pre>` tags `:-)` A tip: If you repair an edit within the 5 minute grace period, then the new Edit Summary will _overwrite_ the previous one. (Have a look at the revision history!)

Comment: @Hendrik: I just found that out by myself! :-) The problem is that I still had my old Greasemonkey script on which also highlights normal `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 9):

I look at the man page again and found the solution.  The call should be:

```
latexmk -bibtex -r latexmrc ipmc
```