# Is there a way to configure Kile to run a certain program?

Tags: windows, kile

Version: Kile 2.1
OS: Windows 7 SP1

I wanted to delete the files that Kile generates at the time it creates a .pdf file from a given .tex file. I can easily compile a program  into a .exe file (say using python) to delete all the files from the folder which don't have the extensions I need (I want to keep the .tex, .pdf files, but I haven't found a use for the files having .log .tex~ and other similar extensions).

Is there a way to assign a shortcut or maybe a button in Kile to call that kind of a .exe file?

Comment: But the other files are necessary too. See e.g. [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files/11130#11130) or [What files are used in the TeX world?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55732/4918).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my Kile version (2.1.0) I do have a "Settings" Menu which has a "Configure Kile" entry. Then I can configure "Build" and "Tools" execute any program I like. In fact, I have it configured to use either latexmk or my Makefile. You can even add buttons to the quick menu.

[image]

Comment: @FrederickNord May I ask which command you use(d) to configure your `latexmk` entry? Would a simple `latexmk -pdf %.tex` (as seen elsewhere in TeX.SE) be enough?

Comment: @FrederickNord ...or maybe similar to `latexmk -bibtex ...` (taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11239/8272)?

Comment: @FrederickNord Complete  your answer by showing your configuration for the command. I cannot get it invoke just `make` without any options.