# What files are used in the TeX world?

Tags: auxiliary-files, big-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File extensions of LaTeX-related files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-of-latex-related-files)
>   [Egad! What are all those files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/egad-what-are-all-those-files)

What are files that LaTeX creates when calling one of it’s programs (including `biber`, `xindy` etc.)? What are files used to create a document?

---

Actually I know the answer but I think it’s a good idee to collect them in one question. I suggest making a CW answer for each “topic” with the following format

```
## Topic

* __`.suffix`:__ Explanatory text
 (When is it created?,
  For what is it used?
  what happens when I delete it? …)  [two spaces, i.e. line break]  
  Created by `program`.
```

Sort the entries alphabetically, please.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [File extensions of LaTeX-related files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7770) and [Egad! What are all those files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53240) (and Will's list: https://github.com/wspr/latex-auxfiles)?

Comment: @Caramdir: Oh, I didn’t found your first link, but I saw Will’s list and thought it would be good to have a list here too. I don’t mind if we close this as duplicate :-)