# Latexmk fails to compile citing missing .bbl file with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, errors, latexmk, makefile, compilation-error

I am trying to use the excellent and well-maintained template/framework here for my phd thesis. https://github.com/holgern/TUB_PhDThesisTemplate since this meets all the requirements of my university.

The supplied makefile uses `pdflatex`/`biblatex` combo and works fine at the command line straightaway. However, thesis writing being a large project, I wish the familiar tool `latexmk` that is integrated into my editor. This helps me to perform continuous compilation and get error/warning feedback -- essentially, running with the `-pvc` options and with `-shell-escape` enabled.

However, `latexmk` fails to compile the project. It complains that the `.bbl` file is not found. The main/root source file is `thesis.tex` and the `latexmk` error message is

```
thesis.bbl not found!
```

The source code correctly sets up a valid bib file:

```
\addbibresource{9_backmatter/references.bib}
```

The supplied makefile has no problems in compiling this project.

Suspecting that there might be a bug in the software, I tried using the latest `latexmk v4.55d` (not available from CTAN yet), downloading it straight from the author's website, but the problem persists.

I wonder what is going on? Can anyone please help?

#### latexmkrc configutration

One of the community members commented below that they were able to run the project. I suspect then that something must be wrong in my project `latexmkrc` config, which I am posting

```
@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "glo-abr gls-abr 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].glo-abr -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].gls-abr"); }
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'glo-abr');

push @file_not_found, '^Package .* No file `([^\\\']*)\\\'';

$bibtex_use=1
```

Comment: `.bbl` file has the name of the main file and different extension (`.bbl`) and this is the correct way to look for it. (So, "latexmk is looking for the wrong .bbl file." is wrong.)

Comment: @koleygr, thank you for pointing this out. I have now changed the title and content of this question to reflect that latexmk has troubles compiling this

Comment: Another possible problem is the underscore (but I suppose you would get an error)... And one more is that latex uses "linux like" paths and sometimes things like `\addbibresource{9_backmatter/references.bib}` are preffered  to be written as:`\addbibresource{./9_backmatter/references.bib}`. Just from experience (but may be I am wrong... Just test it.)

Comment: @koleygr, that did not help. Furthermore, I also tried moving the ```references.bib``` file to the project's root directory and modified the ```addbibresource``` line suitably, again to no avail. I am really confused.

Comment: Heve you used this method? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11239/120578

Comment: I just got the template from GitHub and compiled it with `latexmk` there were no problems with that. A `.bbl` was produced and Biber ran as intended. So there must be something more to it on your side...

Comment: @moewe, I see. Thank you very much for your effort. Something must be different in your root ```.latexmkrc``` that alters the behavior from mine. I shall edit my original post to include my ```latexmkrc``` config for this project.

Comment: I don't have a custom `.latexmkrc`, I use the default settings. Did you try with that? Maybe the `push @file_not_found` line is the culprit. It would be entirely normal for `latexmk` to not find a `.bbl` on the initial TeX run, this is not a problem and should not error out compilation.

Comment: @krishna The message about the bbl file not being found is probably not from `latexmk`, since `latexmk` doesn't have any error messages ending `not found!`, with an exclamation symbol. (I've just searched `latexmk` for that string.) So something else is going on.  It would help to post the output from the run of `latexmk`, or at least the lines around the message.  A detailed reading of the output can often show what the problem is.

Comment: I see the `latexmk` expert has arrived. FWIW the messages produced by TeX also do not have an exclamation mark in `Package biblatex Info: ... file 'thesis.bbl' not found.` and 
`No file thesis.bbl.`

Comment: @JohnCollins, I think this is a problem with my editor plugin ```vimtex``` that fails to pass the option ```bibtex``` in its default configuration. The problem was solved when I included this option. Thank you for your helpful attempt at solving the issue.

Comment: Do you want to type up an answer, so we can mark the question as solved?

Comment: Please consider writing up your solution as an answer in the answer section: It might help other people with a similar problem and shows that the question is answered.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the prompt. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can now confirm that the problem was not with `latexmk`, but rather with an interface to it provided by the `vimtex` plugin for the text editor `vim`.

As per the documentation of `vimtex`, the call to `latexmk` should automatically escape the shell and run `bibtex/biber` as necessary. However, it fails to do so (perhaps a bug in `vimtex`).

I passed this to the relevant `vimtex` dictionary in my `vimrc`

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
            \ 'options' : [
            \   '-shell-escape',
            \   '-bibtex',
            \ ],
            \}
```

the issue disappeared.